# In the NFL, how have teams fared against odds from Las Vegas?

Tags: statistics, nfl, betting

Is a home team more or less likely to beat the spread than an away team? Do favored teams or underdogs win against the spread more often? Please include statistics/studies instead of just guessing.

> Team A is favored by three points. They beat Team B by two points. Team B won against the spread (or beat the spread).
>
> Team A is favored by three points. Team B wins. Team B won against the spread.
>
> Team A is favored by three points. They win by five points. Team A won against the spread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a home team more or less likely to beat the spread than an away team?

Less likely.

Against the spread, the home team is 2001-2074-109 (.47825) since 2003.

[Source](https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/trends/ats_trends/?sc=is_home&range=yearly_all) | Range: Since 2003 | Show: All | Situation: As Home Team

> Do favored teams or underdogs win against the spread more often?

Underdogs win against the spread more often than favored teams.

Against the spread, the favored team is 1999-2068-110 (.4786) since 2003.

[Source](https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/trends/ats_trends/?sc=is_fav&range=yearly_since_2003) | Range: Since 2003 | Show: All | Situation: As Favored Team